# Center label of any size under a button in CSS

Tags: html, css, position

I've got a button with a label absolutely positioned underneath.

I want the label to not wrap to a new line but to be rendered all on one line. I know i can do that with `width: max-content` or with `overflow: visible`.

But at the same time i want the label to be centered with the button, which is what i can't find a way to do unless i wrap the label to a new line.

Any way i can achieve this? [image]

```css
button {
    position: relative;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #E30202;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 14px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(45px);
  left: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  width: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* width: max-content; */
}
```

```html
<button>
  
  <span>Label Line</span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your text is centered. There is just not enough width in the container for the text to fall on only one line. You can use the `psuedo-element` `:after` to add the centered text. But you'll notice the example 1 in the snippet still doesn't seem centered. The `width` of the `button` is doubled on the second example with the same styles showing the centered text.

Another solution would be to add a `.wrapper` and use `display: flex;` with `flex-flow: column;` and `justify-content: center;` to make sure the text is always centered with the button.

```css
button {
  position: relative;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #E30202;
  color: black;
  border-radius: 14px;
  margin: auto;
}

button.pseudo:after {
  content: "Label Line";
  position: relative;
  top: calc(100% + 3px);
}

.btn-wrapper:nth-child(2)>button {
  width: 80px;
}

.btn-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!-- example 1 -->
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <button class="pseudo">
 
</button>
</div>

<!-- example 2 -->
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <button class="pseudo">
 
</button>
</div>

<!-- example 3 -->
<div class="btn-wrapper">
  <button>btn</button>
  <span>Label Line</span>
</div>
```